# Linebreak of words in math mode

Tags: line-breaking

I have some texts in math mode which does not break during justifications.

For example,

```
$A_xB_yC_z$ and $D_xE_yC_z$
```

The above two 'words' if at the end of a line, do not break and disrupts paragraph justification.

Any way to fix this apart from reconstructing the sentence?

Comment: @LudovicC. why "no"? linebrreaking is allowed inline math.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes it is but I answered no maybe too fast thinking of automatic linebreaking and not manual one. And I also considered that mathematical equations should not be spread on two lines when in *in-line maths mode*, but why not for some other maths expressions.

Comment: @LudovicC. This is automatic (more or less)  in that you can add the breakpoint everywhere, and then let the automatic line break algorithm pick it if it wants.

Comment: Sure for this part but you will have to add this in all your in-line maths expressions to make sure not to have overfull hbox in your entire document. I agree it is the solution for a specific case but it might not be as convenient for an entire thesis full of maths expression.

Answer (score 7):

Please always supply a complete test document, not just a fragment. You can add a potential break point using `\linebreak` where the optional argument gives the strength of the hint to break, 0 here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{7cm}

\begin{document}

 x\hspace{4cm}x one two $A_xB_yC_z$ and $D_xE_yC_z$ three four five six seven eight none ten eleven twelve.


 x\hspace{4cm}x one two $A_x\linebreak[0]B_y\linebreak[0]C_z$ and $D_x\linebreak[0]E_y\linebreak[0]C_z$ three four five six seven eight none ten eleven twelve.



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Generally a broken word is indicated by a dash. Here the dash is not there when breaking the 'word'. Is it acceptable in a thesis?

Comment: @cosmicraga you almost certainly never want to introduce a symbol into math mode, too many possibilities of confusion with `-` . It's better not to break really. Given the effort to write a thesis, the effort to reword the paragraph or to use display math is not that great. It is different if you are doing automated typesetting of thousands of pages

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX has the command `\*` for a "discretionary multiplication sign"; using David's sample text, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{7cm}

\begin{document}

x\hspace{4cm}x one two $A_xB_yC_z$ and $D_xE_yC_z$ three four five six seven eight none 
ten eleven twelve.


x\hspace{4cm}x one two $A_x\*B_y\*C_z$ and $D_x\*E_y\*C_z$ three four five six seven 
eight none ten eleven twelve.



\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't indiscriminately add this command, do it only in the final revision stage, when no other remedy (such as rewording, first of all) seems to work.

If you prefer a centered dot rather than the `\times` symbol, add

```
\renewcommand{\*}{%
  \discretionary {\thinspace\the\textfont2\char1}{}{}%
}
```

to your document preamble.

Comment: yes (+1) I wondered about mentioning discretionary but not sure it's any clearer if you are using juxtaposition everywhere else. As we both commented, rewording is a better option in any case:-)